# Xtext: Inferring type in variable declaration not working in interface generation

Tags: java, xtext

I am writing my DSL's Model inferrer, which extends from AbstractModelInferrer. Until now, I have successfully generated classes for some grammar constructs, however when I try to generate an interface the type inferrer does not work and I get the following Exception:

```
0    [Worker-2] ERROR org.eclipse.xtext.builder.BuilderParticipant  - Error during compilation of 'platform:/resource/pascani/src/org/example/namespaces/SLA.pascani'.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: equivalent could not be computed
```

The Model inferrer code is:

```
def dispatch void infer(Namespace namespace, IJvmDeclaredTypeAcceptor acceptor, boolean isPreIndexingPhase) {
    acceptor.accept(processNamespace(namespace, isPreIndexingPhase))
}

def JvmGenericType processNamespace(Namespace namespace, boolean isPreIndexingPhase) {
    namespace.toInterface(namespace.fullyQualifiedName.toString) [
        if (!isPreIndexingPhase) {
            documentation = namespace.documentation
            for (e : namespace.expressions) {
                switch (e) {
                    Namespace: {
                        members +=
                            e.toMethod("get" + Strings.toFirstUpper(e.name), typeRef(e.fullyQualifiedName.toString)) [
                                abstract = true
                            ]
                        members += processNamespace(e, isPreIndexingPhase);
                    }
                    XVariableDeclaration: {
                        members += processNamespaceVarDecl(e)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}

def processNamespaceVarDecl(XVariableDeclaration decl) {
    val EList<JvmMember> members = new BasicEList();

    val field = decl.toField(decl.name, inferredType(decl.right))[initializer = decl.right]
    // members += field
    members += decl.toMethod("get" + Strings.toFirstUpper(decl.name), field.type) [
        abstract = true
    ]

    if (decl.isWriteable) {
        members += decl.toMethod("set" + Strings.toFirstUpper(decl.name), typeRef(Void.TYPE)) [
            parameters += decl.toParameter(decl.name, field.type)
            abstract = true
        ]
    }

    return members
}
```

I have tried using the lazy initializer after the `acceptor.accept` method, but it still does not work.

When I uncomment the line `members += field`, which adds a field to an interface, the model inferrer works fine; however, as you know, interfaces cannot have fields.

This seems like a bug to me. I have read tons of posts in the Eclipse forum but nothing seems to solve my problem. In case it is needed, this is my grammar:

```
grammar org.pascani.Pascani with org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.Xbase

import "http://www.eclipse.org/xtext/common/JavaVMTypes" as types
import "http://www.eclipse.org/xtext/xbase/Xbase"

generate pascani "http://www.pascani.org/Pascani"

Model
    :   ('package' name = QualifiedName ->';'?)? 
        imports = XImportSection?
        typeDeclaration = TypeDeclaration?
    ;

TypeDeclaration
    :   MonitorDeclaration 
    |   NamespaceDeclaration
    ;

MonitorDeclaration returns Monitor
    :   'monitor' name = ValidID 
        ('using' usings += [Namespace | ValidID] (',' usings += [Namespace | ValidID])*)?  
        body = '{' expressions += InternalMonitorDeclaration* '}'
    ;

NamespaceDeclaration returns Namespace
    :   'namespace' name = ValidID body = '{' expressions += InternalNamespaceDeclaration* '}'
    ;

InternalMonitorDeclaration returns XExpression
    :   XVariableDeclaration
    |   EventDeclaration
    |   HandlerDeclaration
    ;

InternalNamespaceDeclaration returns XExpression
    :   XVariableDeclaration
    |   NamespaceDeclaration
    ;

HandlerDeclaration
    :   'handler' name = ValidID '(' param = FullJvmFormalParameter ')' body = XBlockExpression
    ;

EventDeclaration returns Event
    :   'event' name = ValidID 'raised' (periodically ?= 'periodically')? 'on'? emitter = EventEmitter ->';'?
    ;

EventEmitter
    :   eventType = EventType 'of' emitter = QualifiedName (=> specifier = RelationalEventSpecifier)? ('using' probe = ValidID)?
    |   cronExpression = CronExpression
    ;

enum EventType
    :   invoke
    |   return
    |   change
    |   exception
    ;

RelationalEventSpecifier returns EventSpecifier
    :   EventSpecifier ({RelationalEventSpecifier.left = current} operator = RelationalOperator right = EventSpecifier)*
    ;

enum RelationalOperator
    :   and
    |   or
    ;

EventSpecifier
    :   (below ?= 'below' | above ?= 'above' | equal ?= 'equal' 'to') value = EventSpecifierValue
    |   '(' RelationalEventSpecifier ')'
    ;

EventSpecifierValue
    :   value = Number (percentage ?= '%')?
    |   variable = QualifiedName
    ;

CronExpression
    :   seconds = CronElement       // 0-59
        minutes = CronElement       // 0-59
        hours   = CronElement       // 0-23
        days    = CronElement       // 1-31
        months  = CronElement       // 1-2 or Jan-Dec
        daysOfWeek = CronElement    // 0-6 or Sun-Sat
    |   constant = CronConstant
    ;

enum CronConstant
    :   reboot      // Run at startup
    |   yearly      // 0 0 0 1 1 *
    |   annually    // Equal to @yearly
    |   monthly     // 0 0 0 1 * *
    |   weekly      // 0 0 0 * * 0
    |   daily       // 0 0 0 * * *
    |   hourly      // 0 0 * * * *
    |   minutely    // 0 * * * * *
    |   secondly    // * * * * * *
    ;

CronElement
   :    RangeCronElement | PeriodicCronElement
   ;

RangeCronElement hidden()
   :    TerminalCronElement ({RangeCronElement.start = current} '-' end = TerminalCronElement)?
   ;

TerminalCronElement
   :    expression = (IntLiteral | ValidID | '*' | '?')
   ;

PeriodicCronElement hidden()
   :    expression = TerminalCronElement '/' elements = RangeCronList
   ;

RangeCronList hidden()
   :    elements += RangeCronElement (',' elements +=RangeCronElement)*
   ;

IntLiteral
    :   INT
    ;
```

**UPDATE**

The use of a field was a way to continue working in other stuff until I find a solution. The actual code is:

```
def processNamespaceVarDecl(XVariableDeclaration decl) {
    val EList<JvmMember> members = new BasicEList();
    val type = if (decl.right != null) inferredType(decl.right) else decl.type

    members += decl.toMethod("get" + Strings.toFirstUpper(decl.name), type) [
        abstract = true
    ]

    if (decl.isWriteable) {
        members += decl.toMethod("set" + Strings.toFirstUpper(decl.name), typeRef(Void.TYPE)) [
            parameters += decl.toParameter(decl.name, type)
            abstract = true
        ]
    }

    return members
}
```

Comment: You're inferring a field but you don't add it to the resource. That'll never work. The inferred type of the field is basically not contained anywhere thus will never be processed. It should be possible to use inferredType(decl.right) as the return type of the get-method, though.

Comment: @SebastianZarnekow, I updated the question. That was a desperate way to make it work. When I try inferredType(declr.right) the same exception is raised: java.lang.IllegalStateException: equivalent could not be computed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the answer in the Eclipse forum:

> i dont know if that you are doing is a good idea. the inferrer maps
>   your concepts to java concepts and this enables the scoping for the
>   expressions. if you do not have a place for your expressions then it
>   wont work. their types never will be computed
>
> thus i think you have a usecase which is not possible using xbase
>   without customizations. your semantics is not quite clear to me.

[Christian Dietrich](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=usrinfo&id=31875&)

My answer:

Thanks Christian, I though I was doing something wrong. If it seems not to be a common use case, then there is no problem, I will make sure the user explicitly defines a variable type.

Just to clarify a little bit, a Namespace is intended to define variables that are used in Monitors. That's why a Namespace becomes an interface, and a Monitor becomes a class.

[Read the Eclipse forum thread](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=1068888&goto=1703102&#msg_1703102)